# Dynamically get info about other apps in app store in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

There are few paid apps in the Apple app store. I am developing an app where I need to show the info ( localized text, pricing info etc.) about other apps ( the number of apps vary dynamically ) which are already there in app store. How can I get info about other apps dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the iTunes API to get some information, but it's a search APIso you'll need some criteria.

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Apple just recently changed their rules regarding apps that reproduce app store like functionality.

[http://www.tuaw.com/2012/10/03/app-search-engine-chomp-shuts-down-but-is-apple-cracking-down-o](http://www.tuaw.com/2012/10/03/app-search-engine-chomp-shuts-down-but-is-apple-cracking-down-o/)/

Comment: I think you might benefit by going and reading about StoreKit and the iTunes API and so on, so you get more of a feel for what you're able to do versus what you want to do. From the StoreKit docs: "The Store Kit framework provides classes that allow an app to request payment from a user for additional functionality or content that your application delivers." - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/_index.html